# Error getting data from firebase using changes.map in ionic 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to get data from firebase based on the login user ID but i am having error when using changes.map. Error show in vscode is "property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'".

Below is how i am getting the data:

-----------------shopping-list.ts:-----------------

```
userId: string;
private shoppingListRef: any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth){
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data && data.email && data.uid){
        this.userId = data.uid;
        this.shoppingListRef = this.db.list<Item>(`shopping-list/${data.uid}`);
      }
    })
  }

  getShoppingList(){
    return this.shoppingListRef;
  }
```

---------------home.ts:----------------------

```
shoppingList$: Observable<Item[]>;
  userId: string;
  profileData: Observable<Profile>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private shopping: shoppingListService,
    public db: AngularFireDatabase, private toast: ToastService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private account: userAccountService) {}

  ionViewWillLoad(){
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data && data.email && data.uid){
        this.profileData = this.db.object<Profile>(`profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
        this.userId = data.uid;
        this.getItemList();
      }
      else{
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('LoginPage');
      }
    })
  }

  getItemList(){
    try{
      this.shoppingList$ = this.shopping
        .getShoppingList() //this reruns the DB list
        .snapshotChanges() //this gives the keys and value pairs
        .pipe(map(
          changes => {
            **return changes.map(c => ({//this changes.map is where the error is showing**
              key: c.payload.key,
              ...c.payload.val()
            }));
          }
        ));
    }
    catch(e){
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

----home.html------
This is how i display the records

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of shoppingList$ | async; let i=index" (click)="toggleAccordion(i)" [ngClass]="{active: isAccordionShown(i)}" >
```

------Below is my package.jason:--------

```
{
  "name": "shoppingList",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.1",
    "firebase": "^7.15.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.9",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "native-run": "^1.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.3",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

This error Started after i upgraded typescript to the latest using npm i typscript@latest and it updated to version "^3.9.7".

-----Things i have tried-------

- Downgrade the typescript
- Upgrade rxjs and rxjs-compat to 6.5.5,6.3.0,6.2.0
- Created a new project
- Delete node_modules, package-lock.jason, and did npm install

I really need help beause i have been on this for days with no solution. Thanks to you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
I assigned a type of any to shoppingListRef instead of type of AngularFireList

it was initially:

```
private shoppingListRef: any;
```

updated it to:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "angularfire2/database";

private shoppingListRef: AngularFireList<Item>;
```

The above changes solved the problem